# Scalding job failing with VerifyError on EMR version 4.2.0

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, emr, scalding

We have a Scalding job which I want to run on the AWS Elastic MapReduce using release label 4.2.0.

This job ran successfully on AMI 2.4.2. When we upgraded it to AMI 3.7.0, we ran into a `java.lang.VerifyError` caused by incompatible jars. Our project uses version 1.5 of the commons-codec library but earlier, incompatible versions come with the AMI. Similarly, our project uses Scala 2.10 but version 2.11 comes with the AMI. We solved this problem by adding a bootstrap script to delete all files matching `commons-codec-1.[234].jar` or `scala-library-2.11.*.jar` from the cluster.

Now we again want to upgrade to 4.2.0, and again get a VerifyError:

````
```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.twitter.scalding.Job$.apply(Job.scala:47)
    at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.getJob(Tool.scala:48)
    at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.run(Tool.scala:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.hadoop.JobRunner$.main(JobRunner.scala:33)
    at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.hadoop.JobRunner.main(JobRunner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/snowplowanalytics/snowplow/enrich/common/utils/ConversionUtils$.decodeBase64Url(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lscalaz/Validation; @5: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/commons/codec/binary/BaseNCodec'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @5
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/snowplowanalytics/snowplow/enrich/common/utils/ConversionUtils$', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64', 'java/lang/String' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab7 008a 2cb6 0090 3a04 bb00 5459 1904
    0000010: b200 96b7 0099 3a05 b200 9e19 05b9 00a4
    0000020: 0200 b900 aa01 00a7 003e 4eb2 009e bb00
    0000030: ac59 b200 4112 aeb6 00b1 b700 b4b2 0041
    0000040: 06bd 0004 5903 2b53 5904 2c53 5905 2db6
    0000050: 00b9 53b6 00bf b900 c502 00b9 00a4 0200
    0000060: b900 c801 00b0                         
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [0, 42] => handler: 42
  Stackmap Table:
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@42,Object[#182])
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@101,Object[#206])

    at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.hadoop.EtlJobConfig$.com$snowplowanalytics$snowplow$enrich$hadoop$EtlJobConfig$$base64ToJsonNode(EtlJobConfig.scala:224)
    at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.hadoop.EtlJobConfig$.loadConfigAndFilesToCache(EtlJobConfig.scala:126)
    at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.hadoop.EtlJob.(EtlJob.scala:139)
    ... 16 more
```
````

Exploring which jars remain on the cluster following the purge:

```
$ sudo find / -name "*scala-*"
/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/cli/lib/scala-library-2.10.5.jar
/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/cli/lib/scala-reflect-2.10.4.jar
/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/cli/lib/scala-logging-api_2.10-2.1.2.jar
/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/cli/lib/nscala-time_2.10-1.2.0.jar
/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/cli/lib/scala-logging-slf4j_2.10-2.1.2.jar
$ sudo find / -name "*commons-codec*"
/usr/share/aws/emr/node-provisioner/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar
/usr/share/aws/emr/emr-metrics/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar
/usr/share/aws/emr/emr-metrics-client/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar
/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar
/usr/share/aws/emr/hadoop-state-pusher/lib/commons-codec-1.8.jar
/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-codec-1.7.jar
/usr/lib/mahout/lib/commons-codec-1.7.jar
```

The same error occurs with AMI 4.1.0. What has changed between 3.7.0 and 4.x.x which is causing this issue, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I added the following logic in a bootstrap step:

```
wget 'http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.5/commons-codec-1.5.jar'
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/hadoop/lib
sudo cp commons-codec-1.5.jar /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/remedial-commons-codec-1.5.jar
rm commons-codec-1.5.jar
```

This downloads the correct version of the jar from Maven and puts it at the beginning of the classpath for the failing job step, where it takes precedence over other versions of the jar.

Is there a cleaner solution?